# How to make a 3d bubble plot where the bubbles are to scale?

Tags: python, data-visualization, 3d

I have about 100 points that I would like to draw spheres around. The spheres are all of varying radii and have a size with the same units of measurement as the x,y,z axes. I can make a 3d scatter plot with matplotlib and adjust the size of the markers, or even use plotly, but neither option allows me to adjust the radius of a bubble to match the physical units of the axes (meters). This makes it very difficult to adjust bubble sizes according to physical measurements. Basically I am trying to make a scale 3d model that I can move around/see bubbles overlap.

This seems like something that someone must have done before, but I cannot find much help online in my search thus far. Is there any python package that will accomplish this, or anything outside of python?